# Groovy Regexp to extract substring

Tags: groovy

Need to extract only (Sev-1) or (Sev-2) from the following strings using a regexp which suits both

```
1) Sev-1 (Medium)
2) Sev-2 (Medim/minor)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for:

```
def matches = """
1) Sev-1 (Medium)
2) Sev-2 (Medim/minor)
"""=~/(Sev-\d*)/

println matches[0][1]
println matches[1][1]
```

this prints:

```
Sev-1
Sev-2
```

**UPDATE**:

okay, still the regex remains the same:

lets say your string is `s`:

```
def matches = s =~/(Sev-\d*)/
println matches[0][1]
```

You may try both values in `s`

Comment: I was not clear , excuse me the string let us say "s" . This will carry either one of those values in (1) or (2) .
Now need to print the extracted value .